# Make MMS image is clickable using Twilio in java

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hope you are doing great,

I am new for Twilio using java. I am try to sending MMS and i can able to generate MMS using mediaURL with out having issues.

Question: will it be possible to make the image has clickable? i meaning adding  tag in the media url ??

If possible, please help me with some example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you send an image as an MMS what you see is what you get. You can send an image and it will arrive at a user's phone. Depending on the make of their phone or operating system, they may be able to click into the image to inspect it or zoom in.

You can't include anything else as part of the image. You can send [other mime types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types), but these are still just files and can't be interactive.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: i have done html and placed in public accessible place. while i am sending sms manually, from one phone to other phone i am getting preview of the html in message both the sides. but when we try to send sms with only html link i am getting only link not preview.

Comment: I have tried using mms by giving mediaURL providing html link, the mms is failing from twilio side. i can see logs in twilio admin page with my account. in the same place if we give jpg path it's working.  main intend is want to get html preview.

Comment: Question is: How do SMS and MMS URL Link Previews Work on Mobile Devices please let me know your suggestions

Comment: Oh, you want to send an HTML file as a media file? I don't believe that is possible. You can see all of the media types you can send here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types. If you send a URL as part of the SMS body, then some SMS clients will preview the link. That doesn't require MMS though.

Comment: I have sent url manually and I can see preview but same thing if I send using Twilio service through java, I am getting message but exact the url I can see but not preview.

Comment: TwilioRestClient2 client = new TwilioRestClient2(AccountSid,AuthToken);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", fromNumber));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", message));
MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
Message twilioMessage = messageFactory.create(params);

Comment: in the body i am try to sending public link "http://*****-public.s3.amazonaws.com/vehicles/test.html". below is the html file               <html prefix="og: ogp.me/ns#"> <head> <meta property="og:title" content="Mark's Favorites at AEO" /> <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="j-26.com/assets/twitter.jpg"> </head> <body> <p>Web page content goes here</p> </body> </html>                                                                                       if i sending manually i am getting preview, but twilo.  i am getting plain message. did i miss any thing.

Comment: If you are sending it as a URL in the body of the message then I recommend a couple of things: make sure the message is 160 characters or below, make sure the URL is at the beginning or the end of the message and only send one URL per message. It's possible that iOS devices will only display previews to people in the recipient's contacts too. Check out more detail here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013199334-How-do-SMS-and-MMS-URL-Link-Previews-Work-on-Mobile-Devices-

Comment: Ohh, the preview will show only who are there in contact / save numbers only ?? The preview won’t show for new numbers ( I mean we don’t save the numbers in contact list) ??

Comment: That seems to be a restriction in iOS at least. Perhaps it is a security/privacy/risk thing, that if someone is in your contacts they’re less likely to send you something you wouldn’t want, so the preview will show.

Comment: Thanks a alot for helping me. so, my senior won't work to do preview. I appreciate you :-)

Comment: No problem! Hope you get this resolved and can carry on with your app.